# Customize algolia's search box in angular

Tags: angular, algolia, instantsearch.js

I'm using algolia in angular.
There is a search box which I want to customize.
Here is what I have done so far.
.html file -

```
<ais-instantsearch [config]="productsConfig">
    <ais-search-box></ais-search-box>
    <ais-hits>
    </ais-hits>
<ng-template let-hits="hits">
```

.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlOptions } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  environment.algolia_application_id,
  environment.algolia_search_api_key
);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.scss']
})

export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  productsConfig = {
      indexName: 'products',
      searchClient
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

I'm not able to customize search box.
How to customize algolia's seach box in angular?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I suppose that it's only change the .css to `.ais-SearchBox-input`

Comment: @Eliseo I tried that but nothing changed.

Comment: try put the .css in styles.css or using ViewEncapsulation.None

Comment: @Eliseo Still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't customized search box so I tried it in different way.
component file -

```
  getProductList(){
      var parameters = {
        query : '',
        hitsPerPage : 1,
        filters: `doctorId = ${this.doctorId}`
      };
      this.algoliaService.getData('products', parameters)
        .then(data => {
          if( data.hits.length > 0 )
          {
            this.doctorDetails = data.hits[0];
          }       
      })
  }
```

service file -

```
getData(indexName, parameters) : any {
  const index = searchClient.initIndex(indexName);
  return index.search(parameters);
}
```

This way you can get data from in component file, so you need not to customize search. Just need to pass your search box value in parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to refer with regard to the issue : https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/widgets/customize-an-existing-widget/js/

Comment: I followed it but not able to use addWidgets. Can you give any example how to implement it?